# Vertical align of h3-text

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I am having some trouble with my h3 not being aligned at the top of the div (as I trying). Vertical-align and line-height just does not seem to do it. Are there any options that I've overlooked?

Comment: What exactly do you consider "align to the top"? Keep in mind that fonts leave a space above capital letters, so that diacritics have enough space. Compare `A Ä`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reset default browser margins and paddings.

```
h3 {padding:0;margin:0;}
```

Otherwise **post your code** if you want better feedback.

Comment: I can't believe i forgot the margin and padding. It worked perfectly! Thanks alot

Comment: @OptimusCrime - nice - approve answer for others to know it solved.

Answer (score 3):

Relative positioning on the div and absolute top positioning on the h3 is another way of achieving this. Will need to add padding to the top of the div also. E.g.

```
div { position: relative; padding-top: 20px; }
h3 { position: absolute; top:  0; right: 0; left: 0; font-size: 18px; line-height: 20px; }
```

Comment: This is overcoding. Also a good recipe for troubles with content that comes after h3.